# CGContext of type "kCGContextTypeIOSurface"

Tags: ios, core-graphics, iosurface

How do I initialise/create a CGContext of type "kCGContextTypeIOSurface"?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo? Even Google doesn't find a single page for this word.

Comment: Yes, I think the spelling is correct. Apple's PDFKit uses this type of CGContext in the draw function of the PDFPage.